# One regex instead of two?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get rid of php code in a file using regex.  Some of the php is not well-formatted, so that there may be extra spaces and/or line breaks.  As an example:

```
<?php require_once('some_sort_of_file.php'); 
                               ?>
```

I've come up with the following regex which seems to work:

```
$initial_text  = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $initial_text );  
$initial_text = preg_replace('/' . preg_quote('<?php') . '.*?' . preg_quote('?>') . '/', '', $initial_text);
```

but was wondering if there might be a way to just use 1 regex statement, in order to speed things up.

Thanks!

Comment: It probably will be easier to explode the text by "<?php" and "?>" than to do it via regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put it as a single regex using the `s` modifier which will allow the dot to match newline chars too. I added the `i` modifier too to make it case-insensitive.. dunno if you care about that:

`$initial_text  = preg_replace('~<\?php.*?\?>~si', '', $initial_text );`

Comment: Thanks! This did it.  And, though I didn't care about it being case-insensitive, it was a helpful bonus.

Answer (score 2):

An even better way to do it: use [the built-in tokenizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php). [Regexes have problems with parsing irregular languages like PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2057919). The tokenizer, on the other hand, parses PHP code just like PHP itself does.

## Sample code:

```
// some dummy code to play with
$myhtml = '<html>
    <body>foo bar
    <?php echo "hello world"; ?>
    baz
    </body>
    </html>';

// Our own little function to do the heavy lifting
function strip_php($text) {
    // break the code into tokens
    $tokens = token_get_all($text);
    // loop over the tokens
    foreach($tokens as $index => $token) {
        // If the token is not an array (e.g., ';') or if it is not inline HTML, nuke it.
        if(!is_array($token) || token_name($token[0]) !== 'T_INLINE_HTML') {
            unset($tokens[$index]);
        }
        else { // otherwise, echo it or do whatever you want here
            echo $token[1];
        }
    }
}

strip_php($myhtml);
```

## Output:

```
<html>
<body>foo bar
baz
</body>
</html>
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/8NCEcm)

Comment: Glad to help! I have had to use the tokenizer myself recently. I have some files that have code-generating code like `<?php echo '<?php blah...?>'; ?>`, which I needed to clean up. A regex will almost always melt down on that. :)